# ASP.NET MVC + MEF + MefContrib: Can't seem to get metadata from Exports

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I'm using asp.net mvc3 with MEF + MEFContrib to load some services on my controllers. What's happening is that I can load the services - `IEnumerable<IPublishService> publishers` - with the `[ImportingConstructor]` but when I try to load the services with metadata - `Lazy<IPublishService, IPluginMetaData>[] publishers` - I get an empty array.

Any thoughts on why? Thanks.

My code:

```
public interface IPluginMetaData
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Version { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PluginMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public PluginMetadataAttribute(string name, string version)
        : base(typeof(IPluginMetaData))
    {
        Name = name;
        Version = version;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[Export(typeof(IPublishService))]
[PluginMetadata("Default", "1.0.0.0")]
public class SamplePublishService : IPublishService
{

}

[ImportingConstructor]
public HomeController(Lazy<IPublishService, IPluginMetaData>[] publisher /* Empty Array */ , IEnumerable<IPublishService> publishers /* Array with 1 service */)
{
}
```

**UPDATE (based on Daniel answer but still nothing)**

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PluginMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public PluginMetadataAttribute(string name, string version)
        : base(typeof(IPublishService))
    {
        Name = name;
        Version = version;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[PluginMetadata("Default", "1.0.0.0")]
public class GoogleSampleGroupPublishService : IPublishService
{
}

[ImportingConstructor]
public HomeController([ImportManyAttribute]Lazy<IPublishService, IPluginMetaData>[] publisher)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would need to put an `ImportManyAttribute` on the arguments to your constructor, since they are collection imports.  Since one of them is working, I suspect that MEFContrib is doing something so that you don't need to do this, but it only works for `IEnumerable<T>` and not an array of T.  So try changing the first argument to `IEnumerable<Lazy<IPublishService, IPluginMetadata>>`, or adding an `ImportManyAttribute` in front of it.

Some other issues I noticed: Your `PluginMetadataAttribute` is derived from `ExportAttribute`.  The reason you would do that is so that you don't have to put both an export and a metadata attribute on your services.  However, the type that you pass to the base class constructor is the exported contract.  So this should be `IPublishService` instead of `IPluginMetadata`.  Make that change and remove the Export attribute from SamplePublishService.

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel, I've made the suggested changes but still nothing :(

Comment: @Bruno What are you using out of MEFContrib?  Is it possible to try it without MEFContrib and see if it works?

Comment: MEFContrib is used to integrate MEF in the asp.net MVC pipeline, so that, for instance, don't have to decorate my controllers with an [Export] attribute. As I stated, it works if I only try to get the Exports. It fails when I try to get the exports with metadata.

Comment: @Bruno I think there's an issue with how MEFContrib handles the collection and/or metadata imports.  It might have to do with using an array versus an `IEnumerable<T>`.  You might want to look at the next preview release of MEF when it's released.  It should have conventional model support, which would allow you to do things like automatically export all controllers.